# How to decode a HTML single quote entity in a string in Java?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I am trying to decode the HTML single quote entity that I have in a given string using the *replace* method, but it doesn't seem to work that way.
Here is the block of code for testing,

```
String s = "I&#039;ve been going to school since 1999.";
System.out.println(s.contains("&#039"));

s.replace("&#039;", "\'");
System.out.println(s);
```

This is the result I get when I run the above.

```
true
I&#039;ve been going to school since 1999.
```

Why does *contains* method returns true but *replace* method doesn't do anything?

I read some posts about using the Apache commons lang library, but I am not familiar with how to use the library so I was trying to look for a simpler way to fix this.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: because the `replace` method doesn't change the existing string. it returns a modified string. so `s = s.replace(...)`

Comment: Corollary: strings in Java are immutable.  No method can modify a string, so you know automatically that anytime you want to change a string you always have to make a new one (but see `StringBuilder`).

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick replies.